# btrfs on SD card, what does "Btrfs detected SSD devices, enabling SSD mode" mean exactly?

Tags: linux, ssd, btrfs, sd-card, flash-memory

I'm experimenting with using btrfs on my Debian Linux armhf system.  The rfs is on a micro SD card.  On bootup I get the message "Btrfs detected SSD devices, enabling SSD mode".  What features does this SSD mode give me exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional hard drives have a spinning disk platter. This means that filesystems can (and do) perform several optimizations. For example, it will locate segments of a file in a contiguous region of the disk, so that when you read different parts of the file, the kernel doesn't have to wait for the platter to spin to a different place. Another optimization done is to locate often-accessed files near each other. Again, this means that statistically, you will spend less time waiting for the disk platter to turn.

By definition, a solid-state drive doesn't have a spinning platter. This means that all of the optimizations done for spinning-platter devices are a dumb idea. All that SSD mode does is turn these optimizations off. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: OK that is good to know.  Do you happen to know what exactly happens when there's a checksum error when doing a read?  From what I've read an error is logged, but is this returned to the calling application somehow?  On my systems there is no human to read the logs.

Comment: Platters spin all the time and don't move. That's the disk head that needs to move upon a seek instead of reading what's just there.

Comment: @fredbasset ask a new question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the correction; I'll update it in the morning